# Insert New Data using Linq -- WCF Data Services (formerly ADO.NET Data Services)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, wcf-data-services

I am really struggling to insert some data into 2 database tables.

**I am using Linq over WCF Data Services using Entity Framework 4.**

The 2 tables look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Password] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Role] nvarchar(max)  NOT NULL,
    [Account_Id] int  NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_EmployeeAccount]
    FOREIGN KEY ([Account_Id])
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Accounts]
    ([Id])
    ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Each Employee must have just 1 Account. However, an Account may not have any Employees at all.

I have generated the entities, and exposed a DataService which is setup with relaxed access rules:

```
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule( "Accounts" , EntitySetRights.All );
config.SetEntitySetAccessRule( "Employees" , EntitySetRights.All );
```

**Using LinqPad I can successfully insert an single Account row like this:**

```
var context = this;
Account account = Account.CreateAccount(1, "foo@example.com", "p@ssword");
context.AddToAccounts(account);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I can see from SQL Server that the row has been inserted, and LinqPad reports no error.

The problem is when I try to insert both a related Account and Employee row together.

I am sure the code below should work?

```
var context = this;
Account account = Account.CreateAccount(1, "foo@example.com", "password");
context.AddToAccounts(account);
Employee employee = Employee.CreateEmployee(1, "Foo", "Developer");
employee.Account = account;
context.AddToEmployees(employee);
context.SaveChanges();
```

The response I get back from the server (with verbose errors enabled) basically says that:

```
Account row inserted successfully (HTTP 201)
Employee row did not insert (HTTP 500)
```

The full error is:

Entities in 'DbContainer.Employees' participate in the 'EmployeeAccount' relationship. 0 related 'Account' were found. 1 'Account' is expected.

**Does anybody have an example that works against WCF Data Services?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anybody reading this the solution was to add the following line before SaveChanges()

```
context.SetLink(employee, "Account", account);
```

Simply assigning the account to the employee was not enough, a Link also needed to be established.

Comment: Nice one. Booking for later as I am sure I will run into this problem when I start on some WCF data services soon.

Comment: This is the sort of thing that WCF Data Services **should be doing for us** since **in all cases** you have to call `SetLink` after associating two entities.

Comment: Note: If you receive a "not being tracked" exception when calling SetLink, make sure to call `AddToMySource(mySource)` _before_ calling `SetLink(mySource, "Property", myTarget)`